# jQuery UI - programatically move a dropped draggable to another "available" droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a mini form control where I drag several draggables onto a scale. See [my plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/x6V8qG1dwuVnVBgwiM2f?p=preview)

Ideally, whenever I drop a draggable, I would like to do in the `stop( event, ui )` method:

1. check if the droppable already has a draggable (let's call it draggable2)
2. if there is draggable2, I would like to scan my droppables for one that does not have a draggable
3. then move draggable2 to this droppable

Are there APIs/ways to do this programmatically? I know this sounds similar to sortables, but I am **strictly** looking for the ability to

> *move a draggable to a droppable*

and

> *to know if a droppable already has a draggable, and be able to identify the draggable*

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I am on to something, which involves wiring things together using a combination of the droppable's drop event and adding data-attributes to track who is where. Will provide an answer when working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to accomplish this. Although there are no options from the jQuery UI draggables/droppables API, I have managed to track the draggables and droppables by adding unique "id" attributes to track them.

Here is how I approached the following:

> *move a draggable to a droppable*

My approach: Find the coordinates of the target droppable, and update the css of the draggable.

To figure out which dragger was dragged and which dropper received it, I added attributes `dragger-id` and `dropper-id` so I could identify them during the drop event:

```
drop: function( event, ui ){
  // Get the current dragger and dropper ID's
  dropperId = $(this).attr('dropper-id');
  draggerId = ui.draggable.attr('dragger-id');

  // ... more code
}
```

then I calculated the top and left coordinates for the dragger based on the droppable's values. For this, I used the jQuery's [`offset()`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) method.

```
drop_x = $('.droppable').offset().left - $('.draggable').offset().left;
drop_y = $('.droppable').offset().top - $('.draggable').offset().top;
```

Note: I had to do a difference calculation since draggables are positioned relative to where they start.

Finally, I set the `top` and `left` css values:

```
ui.draggable.css('top', drop_y+'px');  // y-axis
ui.draggable.css('left', drop_x+'px'); // x-axis
```

---

> *to know if a droppable already has a draggable, and be able to identify the draggable*

For this, I created yet another attribute on the droppable elements to track the `dragger-id` values. I called it `current-dragger` so that it would be unique and I could query by it. I used `-1` as my default value, meaning "no dragger".

I assigned `current-dragger` in the drop method as well:

```
drop: function( event, ui ){
  // Get the current dragger and dropper ID's
  dropperId = $(this).attr('dropper-id');
  draggerId = ui.draggable.attr('dragger-id');

  // Remove current-dragger value from old dropper (-1 means no dragger)
  $('[current-dragger="' + draggerId + '"]').attr('current-dragger', '-1');

  // Update current-dragger on this dropper
  $(this).attr('current-dragger', draggerId);

  // ... more code
}
```

I suppose there's really no need to do updates to the DOM attributes, so in prod I will be tracking the current dragger inside of a JavaScript mapping object.

For a full working example, [see my updated plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/x6V8qG1dwuVnVBgwiM2f?p=preview)